# Wordpress Header (multiple headers used) showing twice on custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I currently am trying to do multiple headers in wordpress. I want the home page to have a custom header while the rest have a simple menu header. I have done this in the past but its been a long time since ive needed to and cant figure out what im missing this time around.

I have created the custom header php (header-splash.php) and use the code

`get_header('splash');` in the php bracket

on my page-splash.php page to call the header. However when doing this, the header that is the default header is showing up UNDER the content but above the footer for some reason.

You can see an example via a screen shot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPFJo.jpg

Ive been testing a few thing that i have seen for ways to do multiple headers, however none seem to work and are years and years old of articles so im guessing things have changed over the years as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's probably being included by another file then as it doesn't just magically materialize.  If you can't find it you can find where `get_header` is in the wordpress core (`wp-includes/general-template.php`) and either throw an exception (with error reporting on) so you get the stack trace, or you can use [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).  Obviously once you find out where it's being included remove the code.

Comment: Can you show the code of your 'page-splash.php'?